# JavaFX: How can I horizontally center an ImageView inside a ScrollPane?

Tags: javafx, imageview, scrollpane

```
viewScroll.setContent(new ImageView(bigimg));
double w = viewScroll.getContent().getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
double vw = viewScroll.getViewportBounds().getWidth();

viewScroll.getContent().setTranslateX((vw/2)-(w/2));

viewScroll.toFront();
```

I set an ImageView with some Image inside the ScrollPane but the ImageView always goes to the far left corner. Here I'm trying to manually offset the difference, but it doesn't work well. The ImageView goes too far to the right plus it only updates once because it's inside the eventhandler for a button.

Comment: Why do you want to put it in a `ScrollPane` if it is smaller than the `ScrollPane`?

Comment: The images that are loaded may vary in size, and I intended to implement zoom and pan once I figure this out. Trying to get the width by viewScroll.getContent().getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() returns 0 for some reason, which is probably why it goes so far right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using a label without the need for listeners:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    Label label = new Label("Hello!");
    label.translateXProperty().bind(scrollPane.widthProperty().subtract(label.widthProperty()).divide(2));
    scrollPane.setContent(label);
    Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setWidth(200);
    primaryStage.setHeight(200);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

I am not sure if you are familiar with properties or not, but in the code above, when I bind the `translateXProperty` to the formula, every time one of the dependencies changes, such as the `ScrollPane`'s `widthProperty` or the `Label`'s `widthProperty`, the formula is recalculated and `translateXProperty` is set to the result of the formula.

I am not sure, but in your previous code, it appears that the calculation code would be in a resize listener. This is not required when dealing with properties as they update whenever dependencies changed (note the `bind()` and not `set()`).

Comment: Ah, that's it! I've also found using a BufferImage and converting to Image through SwingFXUtils gives me the proper width for ImageView. If you don't mind, could you explain why TranslateXProperty() doesn't just keep incrementing to the right? Thanks

Comment: I would recommenced reading this (fully :)): https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm

Comment: Edit: I guess I'm asking, what is the relationship between LayoutX and TranslateXProperty? As I understand it, setting TranslateX to a different value doesn't affect LayoutX at all and it just applies a new translate every time the value of TranslateXProperty is changed?

Comment: `translateXProperty` is an offset from `layoutXProperty`. The layout sets `layoutXProperty` and other things can set `translateXProperty`.

Comment: I see, thanks. And do you know which property determines the scrollable area? As in, the area where the content lies that you scroll/pan around in. I'm having a problem where the content is being pushed outside the scrollable area and cutoff.

Comment: Yeah, I have always had issues with `ScrollPane`s, I try to avoid them in general. I would reccomend reading the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#hvalueProperty)s for the `ScrollPane`. You might be able to use the `vmax` property to get the maximum scroll width, not sure though. It's worth the playing around!